# AngularJS - Why the application is not routing?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

I'm trying to make an AngularJS application but I don't understand why it doesn't route correctly, I followed some guides but haven´t made it work yet.

Here is the code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="App">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example App</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- Vendor libraries -->
    <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Application Files -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/home/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular
            .module('App', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home/views/index.html',
                controller: 'HomeController',
                controllerAs: 'home'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
})();
```

**HomeController.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
       .module('App')
       .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

    function HomeController(){
        var home = this;
    }
})();
```

**home's index.html**

```
<div>
   Example text
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you can post the most important part of your code here as a snippet instead of referring to an external link? This post will be out-of-date as soon as the link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @BryanOemar Thanks for the advise, I have changed that.

Comment: I don't think you need to be wrapping your code in immediately executing functions. The fact you have included the ng-app attribute means angular will execute your code when required

Comment: This works properly in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dXIaUsReTk9vSxJWShuh?p=preview) (only changing the name of the home index to a plunker friendly format).  If this is not working in your environment, there is something wrong that you are not showing here.

Comment: If I had to *guess*, based on what you have described here so far, and the only change that I made in the example plunker, I would imagine that your `templateUrl` path isn't valid.

Comment: @Claies You are absolutely right it is the template path that is referred from the root directory, even if the app.js file is inside another one. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: so did changing your template path solve your issue?

Comment: @Claies Yes, it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Are you seeing errors in the console? You're probably getting an error relating to the controller not being found, as `'home/controllers/HomeController'` is not a proper way to reference HomeController. It should instead read: `'HomeController'`. Angular will do the work to traverse your controllers and find one that matches that string.

Here's an updated app.js:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular
            .module('App', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home/views/index.html',
                controller: 'HomeController',
                controllerAs: 'home'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
})();
```

Additionally, in HomeController.js, you are re-instantiating the module 'App' by including the brackets after the name. Instead, modify it to more succinctly read:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
       .module('App')
       .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

    function HomeController(){
        var home = this;
    }
})();
```

Comment: I see no error in console, I made the changes you suggested and still not seeing anything.

Comment: Are both angular and angular-route loading properly?

Comment: Yes they are, I found thanks to Claies that the templateUrl was not working properly. But your suggestions helped me a lot too. Thanks.